# Python: using a class in an arithmetic equation?

Tags: python, class, variables, math

I have a class:

```
class Bike(object):
    """Parent class for bikes"""

    def __init__(self, name, weight, cost):
        self.name = name
        self.weight = weight
        self.cost = cost

# Bike designed for children"
bike1 = Bike("Trike", 20, 100)
# Bike designed for everyone"
bike2 = Bike("Kruzer", 50, 165)
# Bike designed for trick parks"
bike3 = Bike("BMX Bomber", 45, 350)
# Bike designed for backcountry trails"
bike4 = Bike("The Roamer", 40, 200)
# Bike designed for intensive mountain riding"
bike5 = Bike("The Avalanche", 70, 700)
# Bike designed for the handicapped"
bike6 = Bike("The Cadi", 120, 1500)
```

In another class:

```
class Shop(object):
    """Parent class for bike shops"""

    def __init__(self, name, inventory, margin, profit):
        self.name = name
        self.inventory = inventory
        self.margin = margin
        self.profit = profit
```

But I can't seem to get this to work:

```
 profit = Bike.cost * margin
```

It always feeds back an error saying 'bike' is not defined, which I assume has something to do with the "bike1 = ...., bike2 = ...."

should that section be indented in order to be blocked with the class? Or is that not even the issue?

Comment: the variable `bike` is never defined anywhere ... you have `Bike` or `bike1`, ... but not `bike`

Comment: I think you haven't provided enough context? Are you doing this in another method of Shop? How are you associating the Bike objects with the Shop?

Comment: Attribute access is via the `.` operator, not `()`:  `profit = bike.cost * margin`

Comment: I changed it to "Bike.cost * margin" yet now it simply says 'Bike' has no attribute 'cost'.

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure the problem is here:

```
profit = bike(cost) * margin
```

This should read:

```
profit = bike1.cost * margin
```

You need to specify the bike you can't just say bike(cost). If you want to do this for all bikes I would suggest putting all the bikes in a list then going over the list with a for statement.

Answer (score 1):

You **can´t** use a **class** (`Bike`) in an arithmetic equation!

To access an attribute of an *object* (e.g. `bike1`) use `objectName.attributeName` (e.g. `bike1.cost`).

To calculate the `profit` of the *object* `bike1` code:

```
 profit = bike1.cost * margin
```